# How to intercept request only from inside the extension using webrequest api in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to intercept API requests for some business logic in my app.

But in the allowed URLs I am right now using `<all-urls>`, but I want to only intercept request which starts from inside the popup of extension

but I also have Iframe inside that popup, and I also want to intercept those requests as well.

Is there a way to check if an intercepted request started inside the extension popup or an iframe inside it?

Comment: Add a custom header to your request with a random value, store it in a global variable, and compare it in webRequest listener.

Comment: u can assume that I don't have control over the iframe's website.. lets say i have loaded google inside iframe and I want to intercept those request initiated by google's homepage.. I cant add header to it

Comment: Those requests will have tabId `-1` and non-zero `frameId` so it's easy to identify.

Comment: Yes I can see that to be the case.. Is this deterministic behavior.. Any documentation for this will really help me

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest

Comment: . Let me check it out.. This will again intercept all requests.. But I can put an if else using this.. But I was looking for anything which I can put in url specifier argument. So that my interceptor doesn't get invoked for all requests in the browser.. Any ways thanks a lot for this

Comment: You can add the listener in your popup script and use `types` to limit it to `xmlhttprequest`, and you can also limit the `urls` if you know beforehand which requests the iframe makes.

Comment: Oh wow.. This might work for me if popup script only catches request from within.. Let me give it a shot.. Thanks a ton

Comment: It will see all requests. The point here is to only have the listener working while the popup is open.

Comment: makes sense, thank you